# Asynchronous post-back without any rendering

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to do asynchronous post-back without any page rendering (even no partial rendering as it done with AJAX update-panel)?

I need it to be completely transparent to the user.

**Update:**
The page contains nested repeaters, with buttons inside repeater's itemtemplate.

When buttons are clicked there is a partial-rendering.
I don't want this.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. If the presentation layer does not contain any content that will be affected by the purpose of the AJAX request, then you won't have any page rendering, full or partial.

You can assess the AJAX response using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to name a couple of tools.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment,

Set [`ChildrenAsTriggers`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/mref/P_System_Web_UI_UpdatePanel_ChildrenAsTriggers.aspx) `= false` on the `<asp:UpdatePanel ...>` if you don't want the content to be re-rendered in response to a child control initiating a partial postback. It is set to `true` by default.

You can set `ChildrenAsTriggers = false` and then explicitly set an `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>` in the `<Triggers>` section of the `UpdatePanel` for those children and their event(s) that you do want the content of the `UpdatePanel` to be re-rendered for.

Comment: The page have nested repeaters with buttons. when the button is clicked the repeaters get re-rendered. (cause they are inside updatepanel) I don't want this.

Comment: Set `ChildrenAsTriggers = false` on the UpdatePanel and then the Repeaters will not be re-rendered

Comment: Yes, this is good. Is it possible to limit this to some controls? Because there is a button ("Update") that I want to render the repeater. - I want to dance on both weddings.

Comment: Yes it is. you can Set `ChildrenAsTriggers = false` and then explicitly set an `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger >` in the `<Triggers>` section of the `UpdatePanel` for those children and their event(s) that you do want the content of the `UpdatePanel` to be re-rendered for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the regular AJAX-dance, and just direct it to a separate handler for doing what you want, without any rendering. Could that work for your scenario? If not, can you elaborate on what you want to acheive?

Comment: you put your data in, you get your content out, in out, in out, shake it all about, you do an insert of content into the DOM, that's what it's all about :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am assuming you are talking about ASP.Net, as you mentioned an update panel.

ASP.Net AJAX will automatically expose web methods on a page and allow you to call those completely on the client. Try [this page](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/ExposingWebServicesToAJAXTutorial.aspx) for more info on exposing web services to client side AJAX.